# What does it say about your underlying system when the granular level is not predictable, but aggregations are?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

This might be too "discussion-y" rather than black-or-white-answer for here, but thought I'd try. If there's a better direction someone can point me, that's fine.

Example: One McDonald's store daily sales might show extremely non-patterned variability - so that forecasting methods just output a mean forecast.

But when one aggregates to say the city level, of all McDonalds' in the city, the sales time series becomes more patterned. And continuing up that hierarchy to say the country level, one might have something close to complete predictability.

Same applies to other dimensions like time. Hourly sales could defy forecasting beyond the mean, but as you aggregate up to day, week, month, year, extremely robust forecastable patterns can "pop up".

My question is: what does this phenomenon of pattern-appearing-out-of-unpatterned-aggregations indicate about the nature of the atomic level system (in my example, the way in which McDonald's works) ?

On the one hand, it sounds very central limit theorem-esque, and on the other hand I'm looking into hierarchical time series forecasting for more info.

What confuses me I guess is that in fourier function approximation, the atomic level IS patterned (functions of a given set frequency), and then summed together to achieve whatever output desired. My questions seems like the opposite situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not sound like a situation where you cannot predict. It sounds more a situation with some inherent randomness that cannot be explained away by available features/covariates/ information. Such inherent randomness will be the most visible at the lowest level of observation,  where outcome data are sparse.

Comment: But at the lowest level - the single McDonald's store in a day in my example, there's LOTS of data (sales) - they're a very busy store pretty much every day. So lack of data doesn't seem to be the issue to me?

Note: to me "inherent randomness" and "not predictable" mean pretty much the same thing, but that's not a dealbreaker issue here.

Comment: I guess, it would be better to say that some of the underlying (often unobserved) events are sparse. E.g. if there was a traffic accident outside the restaurant that blocked the road/evacuation because of a fire alarm/flooded road/robbery in the restaurant/a new food truck parked in the road/whatever, so for a few hours hardly any/fewer customers came in. That is to some extent inherent randomness (perhaps some things are predictable, if you only collect the right data: e.g. local weather conditions, planning permission information on new competing restaurants etc.).

Comment: Ah i got you - lots of random things making the variability. That's a helpful point - thanks! Extending that thought, those random variability-making-events at the granular level average themselves out when aggregated, which is where aggregate smoother-ness comes from.